# Setting up Jasmine & Karma to test Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm just trying to get Karma set up to test my Angular app with Jasmine. I'm getting this error:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.4 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.9.0)]: Connected on socket pxDaOUXMfGXOVL7ZOuPb
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Mac OS X 10.9.0) ItemCtrl should work FAILED
    TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off'
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/macbookpro/Sites/groceries/spec/angular-mocks.js:1917:36)
```

Here's that function in `angular-mocks.js`:

```
afterEach(function() {
    var injector = currentSpec.$injector;

    currentSpec.$injector = null;
    currentSpec.$modules = null;
    currentSpec = null;

    if (injector) {
      injector.get('$rootElement').off();
      injector.get('$browser').pollFns.length = 0;
    }

    angular.mock.clearDataCache();

    // clean up jquery's fragment cache
    angular.forEach(angular.element.fragments, function(val, key) {
      delete angular.element.fragments[key];
    });

    MockXhr.$$lastInstance = null;

    angular.forEach(angular.callbacks, function(val, key) {
      delete angular.callbacks[key];
    });
    angular.callbacks.counter = 0;
  });
```

I think I'm just requiring files in the wrong order in my karma config. Here's my file structure:

`karama.config.js` is in the the same directory `/spec` as the files it's requiring:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'angular.min.js',
      'angular-mocks.js',
      'app_testable.js',
      'app_spec.js'
    ],
```

`app_testable.js` is a stripped down version of my app with no dependencies except angular. Here's my test. I'm just trying to get `true` to be `true`.

```
'use strict';

describe('ItemCtrl', function(){
  var scope;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('Grocerease'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $controller('ItemCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    })
  );

  it('should work', function(){
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

How do I need to set up karma so that it is able to run the tests correctly?

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: No. The only files I'm using are listed above. As an aside, I didn't include angular-resource because I'm not using the router module. Is that required?

Comment: angular-resource is not for router module but to handle "resources" from REST APIs. Recheck that you are not missing any dependency that might be using at index.html

Comment: btw, did you check at console of the browser for any additional info?

Comment: Indeed I did. Same error as above, referencing the same line in `angular-mocks`.

Comment: what version of angular you are working with? angular and angular-mocks files are both same version?

Comment: @dimirc, I was wrong. The `angular-mocks` was a newer version. Would you submit your answer and I'll mark it correct? Thanks a lot for suggesting that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems like a dependency was incorrectly loaded.

What version of angular are you working with? The 'angular' and 'angular-mocks' files should be the same version.